# Why is my Rhino ETL process failing silently?

Tags: rhino-etl

I have the following Rhino ETL process which fails silently.  The process executes just fine however no round-trips are ever made to the DB, no exceptions are thrown and no data is ever inserted.

```
public class UpdateLeadSources : EtlProcess 
{


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Register(new ConventionInputCommandOperation("MoxyVote")
                     {
                         Command = "Select * from dbo.LeadSources"
                     });
        Register(new ConventionOutputCommandOperation("MoxyDataWarehouse")
                     {
                         Command = "Insert into dbo.LeadSources (LeadSourceID, LeadSourceCategoryID, LeadSourceCode, LeadSourceFriendlyName, Description, IsActive, Password, TopEntityID, TopEntityTypeID, CampaignID) Values(@LeadSourceID, @LeadSourceCategoryID, @LeadSourceCode, @LeadSourceFriendlyName, @Description, @IsActive, @Password, @TopEntityID, @TopEntityTypeID, @CampaignID)"
                     });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rhino etl will catch all exceptions, log them and add them to a collection of errors you can access the collection from the EtlProcess class.
https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-etl/blob/master/Rhino.Etl.Core/EtlProcess.cs#L161 line 161 GetAllErrors()

Comment: I'd misconfigured my logging class so it wasn't showing up. My underlying issue was an insufficiently specific class name in the provider property.

Comment: +1 for the line number querystring parameter! I didn't know github could do that!